# Creating List of Lists in Erlang

Tags: list, erlang

For example I have a list `[1,3,5]` and another list `[2,4,6]`, how do I append these two lists in such way it will form into a List of Lists like this: `[[1,3,5],[2,4,6]]`?

How do I manipulate the list if I add another list at the end `[7,8,9]` to look like `[[1,3,5],[2,4,6],[7,8,9]]`?

Comment: Side comment: In erlang, if you have `L = [A, B]` in a list and want to add `C`, we usually add `C` to the front: `[C | L]` which is the same as `[C, A, B]`. Insertion in the tail-end of a list is very expensive as the list grows large.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
L1 = [1,3,5], 
L2 = [2,4,6],
[L1,L2].
```

Answer (score 5):

You just need create a list containing both lists.

```
A = [1,3,5],
B = [2,4,6],
[A, B].
```

Answer (score 3):

```
-module(lol).
-export([new/0, append/2, head/1, tail/1]).

new() -> [].

append(H, []) when is_list(H) -> [H];
append(H, T) when is_list(H) -> [H | T].

head([H | _]) when is_list(H) -> H.
tail([_ | T]) -> T.
```

In the shell you could then:

```
> Herp = lol:append([1,3,4], lol:new()).
[[1,2,3]]
> Derp = lol:append([4,5,6], Herp).
[[4,5,6],[1,2,3]] 
> lol:head(Derp).
[4,5,6]
```

I leave the rest as exercise for the user.

Answer (score -1):

```
1> [1,2,3 | [1,2,3]].
[1,2,3,1,2,3]
2> lists:append([1,2,3], [1,2,3]).
[1,2,3,1,2,3]
```